# Exclusion principle implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have found a code that uses [exclusion_principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to solve a [Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack18/challenges/candles-2). I understand most part of it but i can't understand how **exclusion principle** is applied , please help me understand it.

**Problem**
I have an array of elements. Each element has a height Hi and a colour Ci. I have to find the number of sequences of elements, which are strictly increasing by height and contain all possible colurs (from 1 to K).

I can found out the numbers of increasing sequence by using BIT algorithm but the problem is how i fullfill the second condition i.e. each sequence contains at least one element of all the avaliable colours.

Example: (height in first column and colour in the second)

```
4 3
1 1
3 2
2 2
4 3
```

**two valid subsequences are (1, 2, 4) and (1, 3, 4)**

Code:

```
int res = 0;
  for(int mask = 0; mask < (1 << K); mask ++){
    memset(ft, 0, sizeof ft);
    int tmp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      if((mask >> (C[i] - 1)) & 1){
        dp[i] = 1 + query(H[i] - 1); // BIT Query function
        madd(tmp, dp[i]);
        update(H[i], dp[i]); // BIT update function
      }
    }
    if(__builtin_popcount(mask) % 2 == K % 2){
      madd(res, tmp);
    } else {
      madd(res, mod - tmp);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly do you need help with? (see also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278797/509868)

Comment: @anatolyg would you please help me or provide me some direction

Comment: Your link is broken (requires subscription or some such); please describe the problem you are trying to solve (edit your question and add the problem's description).

Comment: @anatolyg you need to login to see the editorial. However you can see the statement [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack18/challenges/candles-2)

Comment: I have edited the question; I hope I didn't do any radical change and didn't remove valuable data. Please revert or correct if I did wrong.

Comment: thanks @anatolyg for making my question more clear!!!!

Comment: This shouldn't be closed as too broad since there is a specific question here.  Namely, "How do I use Inclusion-Exclusion to count only sequences with all colors?"  And the answer is, "The sum over subsets `S` of the color of `(-1)**(size(S)) * count(rising sequences without anything in S)`."  Might be better on a math forum though since most programmers don't understand inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the details, but here is a general idea.

Consider a set of different, simpler questions:

> Take some proper subset of the existing colours 1...K.
>   How many legal (according to height) sequences you can make, when you are not allowed to use this subset of colours (but are not obliged to use any colour)?

To answer these questions, it's easy to use BIT ([binary indexed tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree)).

The code represents a subset by a number `mask` in the range `0...2**K` (where `2**K` is calculated as `1 << K`; 0 represents the full set of colours, so it should not be used, but see below).

To answer the original question, you have to iterate over *all* subsets of colours, and apply the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) on the results. Each individual result measures the set of all sequences that don't contain some colours. So the untion of all these sets has precisely the sequences of elements that don't contain some colour. And the answer to the original question is a complement of this set.

The code calculates the size of the full set of sequences together with all other calculations; conceptually, it doesn't belong there, but it's natural to calculate it in the same loop.